# I have a value in a table but when I try to verify if the value is there it returns false

Tags: python, pandas

I have a value in a table but when I try to verify if the value is there it returns false. I am quite new in python, and I have no ideia how to fix this.

When I make:

```
df.iloc[1207]
```

it returns

```
phone            21964258763
account_id_nk       35904690
Name: 1207, dtype: object
```

but when I try:

```
35904690 in df
```

the answer is

```
False
```

Comment: `df.isin([35904690])`

Comment: Using this the result is still False :(